# Symfony 1.4 form with two models binding issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I'm working on a form with Symfony 1.4.
It is based on one model but also another model.
The form works, but I can't retrieve POST data when binding.

Here are the models :

```
ModelA
  id
  text
  something_else_id
```

.

```
ModelB
  id
  name
  modele_a_id
```

And here is how the form looks like :

```
[] modele_b_entry_name_1
[] modele_b_entry_name_2
[] modele_b_entry_name_3

text
[_______________________________]

[ Submit ]
```

I tried to do a `var_dump($request->getParameter('model_a_form'))` and this is what I got :

```
array (size=5)
  'id' => string '20' (length=2)
  'modele_b_entry_name233' => string '233' (length=3)
  'modele_b_entry_name236' => string '236' (length=3)
  'text' => string 'hello world' (length=11)
```

The values are correct.
Thought, the binding doesn't work at all.
When I do that :

```
$form = new ModelAForm();
$form->bind($request->getParameter('model_a_form'));
var_dump($form);
```

I get the form with an array of null data.
Of course the validation doesn't work, when I try a `$form->renderGlobalErrors()`, I get the following message : `Unexpected extra form field`.

Now I'm thinking of using the POST data directly, without using the binding and validation, except if there is a way to correct that.

Thank you for your help !

Edit :

```
public function configure()
{
  unset($this['created_at'], $this['something_else_id']);

  $model_a_id = $this->getObject()->getId();

  $tabModelB = ...; // Query to get all the ModelB in array.

  $this->generateCheckboxList($tabModelB); // Method which add the checkboxes to the widget schema.

  $this->getWidgetSchema()->moveField('text', sfWidgetFormSchema::LAST);
}
```

Comment: `new ModelA()` does not look like a form class. Are you sure you're using the correct class here?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it wrongly, it's well a form class.

Comment: Can you also paste the `configure()` method of your `ModelAForm`?

Comment: I pasted it. For the moment I did what I had to do without the binding and it works. But I think it's safer with Form method ?

Comment: Maybe I have to create a form for each model, and then include a collection of the second model in the first one ? Is it possible with SF1.4 ? I have to check that...